# Three.js from CanvasRenderer to WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to "convert" a Three.js written script that uses a Three.js CanvasRenderer to a WebGLRenderer one and if so how?

Comment: the simple thing to do is to just change your renderer and see what happens.

Comment: Getting an unknown value "offset" in the library itself

Comment: link with the non-minified version of three.js see where the error is and see which one of your calls is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: yes.

And in general you'll get better performance, though you might have a different-looking result.

A very important difference is that you can't use the renderer .domElement as a Canvas-2D because the WebGL renderer is 3D. So if you've been using canvas commands to, say, draw text, you might have some work ahead to adapt them.